# Public Getter is not accessible in other class - Java

Tags: java

I have created a class that extends JButton which I pass to another class constructor. However, when I am trying to access button`s 'getSubmitted()' method it pops me an error message saying that 'Cannot resolve method getSubmitter()'... 
I cannot understand why is that happening as the methods and classes are both public and Button is assigned to a variable...

```
public class ButtonSubmit extends JButton{
   private boolean submitted;
/*
...
*/
public boolean getSubmitted(){
   return this.submitted;
}

public class ServerConnector{
   privaet JButton submitBtn; 
   public ServerConnector(JButton submitBtn){
      this.submitBtn = submitBtn;
   }
   /*..*/
   public void start(){
      while(true){
         if(this.submitBtn.getSubmitted()){
             /**/
          }
      /**/
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because `submitBtn` is `privaet` instead of `private`?

Comment: @Codeer that wouldn't even compile, so I guess it's just a typo when creating the example

Comment: Or maybe you wrote `getSubmitter()` instead of `getSubmitted()` (exchange r with d in the method call)?
In your question the error message says `getSubmitter()`, is that just a typo, too?

Comment: `submitBtn` is a `JButton`, not a `ButtonSubmit`.

Comment: Anyway, `sumbitBtn` is of type `JButton`, not `ButtonSubmit`, so it doesn't have that method. You need to cast it

Comment: It is just a typo sorry...

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I know that wouldn't compile. I believe current error is also an compile error.

Comment: @Codeer yeah, sorry, I meant that it wouldn't show the error OP is complaining about

Comment: Federico klez Culloca - So in order to access the methods I don`t need to assign it as a generic type, right?

Comment: No, you need to cast it. Like `(ButtonSubmit)(this.submitBtn).getSubmitted()`. Or declare it as a `ButtonSubmit` in the first place

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the type `ButtonSubmit` in the constructor and for the field:

```
public class ServerConnector{
   private ButtonSubmit submitBtn; 
   public ServerConnector(ButtonSubmit submitBtn){
      this.submitBtn = submitBtn;
   }
   /*..*/
   public void start(){
      while(true){
         if(submitBtn.getSubmitted()){
             /**/
          }
      /**/
      }
    }
}
```

You are trying to access a member of a type (`JButton`) that doesn't have the desired method. So you need the type `ButtonSubmit` that actually has this method.

Comment: @LioxaZAICHIK So you should upvote an accept the answer

Comment: At least the answer isn't accepted yet. But no hurry.